# What is a Tri-State area?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[image]

There was a murder case, the officer said the bulletin was put out *all the pawn shops and jewelers in the **Tri-State area***.

[image]

The translation says the Tri-State area is the junction area of the three states (the yellow circle area.)

But I searched the image that it may be the entire area of the three states (red area.)

Which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the circle, you can expect on any given day to see someone who was in one of the other states last night.  That is not true of Albany or Buffalo.  I understand *tri-state area* to mean the area that is **affected** by the proximity of the other states.

If the speaker meant the whole of the three states, I'd expect phrasing more like “all the pawn shops in three states” – and within the circle there would be little doubt as to which three.

(Disclaimer: this is only my impression from television; I have never visited *that* tri-state area.)